# How to change adaptiveThresholdImage output color in Imagick?

Tags: replace, colors, output, imagick

Is it possible to change or replace output colors in Imagick adaptiveThresholdImage?

I use this code: http://phpimagick.com/Imagick/adaptiveThresholdImage

```
function adaptiveThresholdImage($imagePath, $width, $height, $adaptiveOffset)
{
$imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
$adaptiveOffsetQuantum = intval($adaptiveOffset * \Imagick::getQuantum());
$imagick->adaptiveThresholdImage($width, $height, $adaptiveOffsetQuantum);
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
}
```

I made a picture with PS, what I need via adaptiveThresholdImage:
[what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Q3l.jpg)

Unfortunatelly I can't any informations from output formatting.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want each pixel of the output image to be a at least a certain shade of gray, or the brighter color from the output of adaptiveThresholdImage.

Probably the easiest way to do that is add:

```
$imagick->evaluateimage(\Imagick::EVALUATE_MAX, 0.5);
```

To after the call to adaptiveThresholdImage.